# React handle issue of separate audio for each item in mapped array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to play an `audio` file each time a user clicks on an `li` element created after mapping over an array.

In my React class I am passing in an (called `songs`) array of objects  as props that look like this:

```
const songs = [{
    name: 'Oasis',
    url: 'oasis.mp3'
  },
  {
    name: 'Blur',
    url: 'blur.mp3'
  },
  {
    name: 'U2',
    url: 'u2.mp3'
  },
];
```

The issue I am having is that the audio keeps playing over the previous track. I understand that this is because the reference to `audio` is different in each instance of an `li` as I have mapped over the array. I want the same reference to the `audio` so I can ensure that only one `audio` file plays at a time. I also have a `prop` that determines whether an `audio` file is currently playing.

Does anyone know how to overcome this?

```
class Audio extends Component {

    render() {

       this.props.songs.map(song => {

          let audio;

          const playSong = () => {

            if(!this.props.audioPlaying){
               audio = new Audio(song.url);
               audio.play();
            } else {
               audio.pause();
               audio = new Audio(song.url);
               audio.play();
            }
          }

         return (
           <li onClick={ playSong }>Play { song.name }</li>
         );
      };

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try it this way

```
class Audio extends Component {

    static audio;

    playSong = (song) => {
        if(!this.props.audioPlaying){
            this.audio = new Audio(song.url);
            this.audio.play();
        } else {
            this.audio.pause();
            this.audio = new Audio(song.url);
            this.audio.play();
        }
    }

    render() {
       this.props.songs.map(song => {
         return (
           <li onClick={(song) => this.playSong(song)}>Play { song.name }</li>
         );
      });
    }
};
```

Comment: You can't do `var audio` in a class like that as far as I am aware

Comment: Please check now

Comment: @peterflanagan, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39626657/reactjs-accessing-variables last answer.

Comment: Can you please make plnkr or jsfiddle for this ?

Comment: with a bit of playing around it worked. cheers. I used `static audio` instead, but same thing. I will give you the green tick

Comment: @peterflanagan, thanks that green tick made my day, 7k :)

Comment: haha! good man! enjoy! 7k is good going! just so you know static doesn't go in the constructor like that. I have edited the answer

Comment: @peterflanagan, Thanks :D